# Logical operators

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I have come across an answer and I can't seem to figure out why it's right.

So there are two int variables x and y and they represent 0x66 and 0x39 respectively.

The question asked what is the result value based on the expression.

```
x && y is apparently 0x01 (1)
x || y is 1
!x || !y is 0
x && ~y is 1
```

From what I was thinking, I thought as long as an argument was not zero it was considered true. So as long as x and y were some non-zero value then && operator would produce a 1, and of course as long as one of them is true the || operator would produce a 1.

So why is the third question 0? Is the ! different from the bitwise ~ operator? So originally x is 0101 0101 in binary since it's non zero it is true in the logical sense, but the ! of it would be false or would it do the one's complement of the number so its 1010 1010?

Comment: The answer partially depends on the specific language and how that language handles logical operators on integer values...

Comment: @deceze Sorry about that, I am referring to C language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I was thinking, I thought as long as an argument was not
>   zero it was considered true. So as long as x and y were some non-zero
>   value then && operator would produce a 1, and of course as long as one
>   of them is true the || operator would produce a 1.

This is all correct.

```
So why is the third question 0? Is the ! different from the bitwise ~ operator?
```

Yes. It is logical NOT. Just like the other logical operators `&&` and `||`, it only cares about if a variable has a non-zero value or not.

`!0` will yield `1`.

`!non_zero` will yield `0`.

---

Note that all logical operators in C yield type `int` rather than `bool`, as an ugly, backwards-compatibility remain from the time before C had a boolean type. In C++ and other C-like languages, logical operators always yield type `bool`.

Similarly, `true` and `false` in C are actually just macros that expand to the integers `1` and `0`. In other languages they are keywords and boolean constants.

Answer (score 1):

A boolean result is always true or false, and in C true is represented by `1` and false by `0`.

The logical not operator `!` gives a boolean result, i.e. `1` or `0`. So if an expression is "true" (i.e. non-zero) then applying `!` on that expression will make it false, i.e. `0`.

In your example you have `!x || !y`. First `!x` is evaluated, and it evaluates to false, leading to `!y` being evaluated, and it also evaluates to false, so the while expression becomes false, i.e. `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `!` is different from the bitwise not `~`. It's a logical not. It yields either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

~(0x01) will 0x10 and
!(0x01) will 0x00

'~' is a bitwise operator. 
'!' is a logical operator.